# Can Boruto awaken Tenseigan?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I heard that Tenseigan can be awakened by those having both Otsutsuki and Hyuga blood lines. Boruto has Otsutsuki blood from Naruto (A descendant of Hagaromo Otsutsuki) and Hyuga blood from his mother. Can he awaken the Tenseigan?

Comment: Nothing is impossible but we can't say anything right now. This link might help you : http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:160215

Comment: Tenseigan it's byakugan with otsutsuki chakra. Boruto have no byakugan.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment it is possible, due to the Uzamaki clan being very vaguely related to Hagaromo (It has been a lot time for dilution of the bloodline). So he could end up with the Tensaigan, but it would be much more likely for the Tensaigan to appear in the theoretical children of Boruto and Sarada, due to Sasuke's bloodline having the optical powers of Hagaromo. 
So to sum it up, Boruto could end up with the Tensaigan some time in the foreseeable future.

Comment: **If you can provide reliable source of this information then it will be good.** 
But don't you think that for Tenseigan, Byakugan is necessary. For Example in wiki it states that - "The combination of the Byakugan and the chakra of an Ōtsutsuki clan member can evolve the Byakugan into the Tenseigan"  Also " Toneri Ōtsutsuki, who awakened the Tenseigan by kidnapping Hanabi Hyūga and stealing her Byakugan" ... So it sums up that Byakugan is necessary but Boruto has no Byakugan so no tenseigan. But there might be possibiity of Himawari to awaken it.

Comment: @LightYagami I think you should post your comment as a answer.

Comment: remember, the Hyuga too have Optical powers, specifically from Kaguya herself, and Naruto is practically Ashura, which gives him a near direct bloodline link to the Otsutsuki. Also @LightYagami Himawari and Boruto were supposed to have the Byakugan, but they were forgotten to be drawn in. Himawari shows her Byakugan the day Naruto Became Hokage (and hit his chakra point, knocking him out cold for the day, so Konohamaru had to Transform and take his place), so Boruto likely will be able to have it one day.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Boruto's eye is a completely new ability that we have not seen yet.

First of all, Boruto's eye is not a byakugan. This is pretty obvious because it looks COMPLETELY different from byakugans(no veins, only in one eye, different color). It may have similar abilities as the byakugan, but it is not the byakugan.

Secondly, his eyes are not the tenseigan either because it looks completely different as well. Sure, both may have blue, but the blacked out portion of Boruto's eye indicates a clear separation from the tenseigan. The tenseigan also doesn't have the curse mark like thing around the eye that the older version of Boruto appears to have (see image below). The tenseigan can only be acquired by combining the chakra of the Hyuga clan and the Otsutsuki clan. Boruto has Hyuga clan chakra but not Otsutsuki clan. Further evidence of this is when Boruto speaks with the ghost of Momoshiki Ōtsutsuki after his fight with him. Momoshiki points out Boruto's Hyuga heritage/chakra but makes no note of any dormant Otsutsuki chakra, which he definitely would have if Boruto did have any dormant Otsutsuki chakra. Also, it is stated nowhere that the tenseigan is able to see the "evil chakra" that Boruto's eye can see.

What Boruto's eye can be is a product of combining the chakra of Asura with the chakra of the Hyuga clan. This would yield a completely new kekkei genkai.

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: The Karma seal has nothing to do with Boruto's Jougan nor does it have anything to do with Tenseigan. The curse mark and Jougan are two completely different abilities, otherwise the eye and curse mark would sync and make his Jougan always active when Karma is activate.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment also nothing is impossible so anything can happen. But according to current information it is not possible for Boruto to awaken Tenseigan. Let me explain why I said this:

> The combination of the Byakugan and the chakra of an Ōtsutsuki clan
>   member can evolve the Byakugan into the Tenseigan.

So it pretty much explain that it can **Evolve** Byakugan to Tenseigan by having chakra of an Ōtsutsuki clan.

So by current definition of this, it is important to have Byakugan. Since Boruto has no Byakugan so we can say that he won't be able to have Tenseigan.

Also according to this [link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:160215) there is one answer which really creates a little confusion but also gives us hope of some possibility :

> We know that
>
> Rinnegan = Asura + Indra (Sharingan)
>
> Tenseigan = Otsutsuki + Hyuga (Byakugan)
>
> Given that they're the children of Naruto and Hinata, Boruto and
>   Himawari's heritage would thus be:
>
> Asura + Hyuga (Byakugan) = ????????
>
> So, it's entirely possible that a unique mixture of Hagaromo's and
>   Hamura's chakras will result in these two, awakening a new dojutsu
>   altogether. This could also explain why both of them lack the
>   Byakugan, as well as their teal-colored eyes.

Comment: Boruto did not have the Byakugan because Kishimoto forgot to draw it, that being said, so did Himawari but she obtained it when her stuffed animal was destroyed and she used it to Knock her father unconscious in one blow.  Its likely the Byakugan works like the Sharingan for those that are not pure hyuga, but we only really have himawari as a direct example, though Itachi's Novel story did have someone with a similar ability, which would make 2 known canon cases.

Comment: As I said in answer with current information we had it is not possible for boruto to have tenseigan but if we will talk about what will happen in futute then it will be purely based on our opinion rather than on facts which I believe can create a huge debate rather than coming to a conclusion.

Comment: `Asura + Hyuga (Byakugan) = ????????` You are forgetting Asura **IS an Otsutsuki** so it is actually `Otsutsuki+ Hyuga (Byakugan) = Tenseigan` So the correct answer is yes he can get a Tenseigan

Comment: Also, Naruto is an Uzumaki which is a descendant of the Otsutsuki's from Asura's side

Answer (score 0):

There is very good reason Boruto could awaken it. However, it requires him to awaken or obtain Byakugan as well as have all of the Bijuu chakra from his dad implanted within him somehow. If those conditions were fulfilled, which they could be easily, the Tenseigan should develop from his Byakugan. The nine Bijuu chakra would fulfill having Otsutsuki chakra since Naruto's chakra is Six Paths' chakra.

Comment: Naruto is Ashura's Transmigrant, so he practically is an Otsutsuki.